# Solicito inclusão de TAG para o CMS "Plone"

Tags: suporte, tag-específica

Solicito inclusão de TAG para o CMS **Plone** que é muito usado no governo e por isso está ganhando espaço na comunidade. Fiz uma pergunta recentemente mas não pude criar a tag por ter menos pontos que o necessário.

Comment: Está bom do jeito que editaram? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81454/3117